# Differential equation problem (ODE)

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I'm having a really hard time solving the following differential equation:

[image: problem]
  So far I have found C = y-2ln(xy)+xy+x but my webwork says it's wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rearranging the given ODE, one obtains

\begin{align*}
& \left(1 - \frac{2}{y} + x\right)y^{\prime} + y = \frac{2}{x} -1 \Longleftrightarrow y^{\prime} - \frac{2y^{\prime}}{y} + xy^{\prime} + y = \frac{2}{x} - 1 \Longleftrightarrow\\\\
& y^{\prime} - \frac{2y^{\prime}}{y} + (xy)^{\prime} = \frac{2}{x} - 1 \Longleftrightarrow y - 2\ln|y| + xy = 2\ln|x| - x + k
\end{align*}

where the last step results from integrating the previous ODE.

Comment: Thank you I was just missing the absolute values on ln! @user1337